cnf template for schedule instead of rule
This section of my cloudformation template creates the Rule correctly but that rule is not executed.
  CronjobsScheduledRule:
    Type: 'AWS::Events::Rule'
    Properties:
      Description: Scheduled Rule
      ScheduleExpression: cron(0 7 ? * * *)
      State: ENABLED
      Targets:
        - Arn: !GetAtt 
            - DailyCostAlert
            - Arn
          Id: TargetFunctionV1

I created a new "schedule" and that is executed as expected.
How do I convert this rule template to schedule?
